# Laravel API cors - request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: php, angular, laravel, cors

I'm having a CORS issue between my Laravel api and Angular client application.

This is my cors middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT"')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type');        }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/advertisement/31/upload-image' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The Network response gives me a 200 response code. So I'll post the headers I get.

[image: Network Img]

Angular is on localhost:4200
Laravel is on 127.0.0.1:8000

bootstrap/app.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

// $app->middleware([
//     Vluzrmos\LumenCors\CorsMiddleware
// ]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

return $app;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing add 'Authorization' to your 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'

```
->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
```

If your problem persist you might implement [vluzrmos/lumen-cors](https://github.com/vluzrmos/lumen-cors)

Comment: I get the following error now Despite the face my origin is localhost not *>Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4200/advert/create' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/advertisement/32/upload-image') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: ok set your ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Comment: I had to change that previously as I was getting this error > The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Comment: In that case this could be a better option https://github.com/vluzrmos/lumen-cors

Comment: I've tried the spatie package for cors and I'm still getting errors It's actually such a joke.

Comment: I have worked with lumen, ionic and angular. I had that same problem and that library worked like a charm.

Comment: The lumen-cors one? I'll give it a shot anyway

Comment: Yes `composer require vluzrmos/lumen-cors`

Comment: Still getting errors. I want to cry hahaha

Comment: Did you add it to your __bootstrap/app.php__? `$app->middleware([
    Vluzrmos\LumenCors\CorsMiddleware::class
]);`

Comment: Not to bootstrap. To the Kernel.php

Comment: Add `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` and Remove `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')`

Comment: Add it to your __bootstrap/app.php__ after your `$app->configure(foo)` and `$app->register(var)`

Comment: I don't have $app->configure(foo) and $app->register(var)

Comment:  put it before `$app->router->group([`...

Comment: I have none of that in my bootstrap/app.php

Comment: I'll add the file to the post

Comment: Oooo xD you can put it before `return $app;` jaja it looks like a lumen 5.2

Comment: Thats registered the next issue is > Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::middleware()

Comment: Did you ran `composer require vluzrmos/lumen-cors` ?

Comment: Yea, thats what I didi

Comment: ‍♂️ Then I don't know because that feature supposed to be in lumen 5.x https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Answer (score 1):

You should add `X-Requested-With` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With');        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try make the following correction

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization');        
}
```

Remember to change the Asterisk(*) to your production URL, when migrating to production (for security reasons)